# Stick Video Playback on one Monitor in fullscreen on all Spaces

Tags: mac, video, osx-spaces

I have a two monitor setup on my Mac. I want to be able to watch a movie on one screen in full screen while working on the other screen. The catch: I am using spaces and move around them very often. I didn't find a player that was able to stick to the monitor on all spaces.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What happens when you configure your movie player to appear on all spaces? `System Preferences`, `Expose and Spaces`, `Spaces`, add the player to the list and select `Every Space`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniels Solution was correct:

Go into `System Preferences`, `Expose and Spaces`, `Spaces`, add the player to the list and select `Every Space`